# Why sometimes the hinge is offset from the door/jamb?

Tags: doors, hinges

This is how I understand hinges should be installed, fully seated with the pin as close as possible to the door.

[image: fully seated hinge]

But I've seem the following many times, where the hinge is installed offset and the pin stands proud of the door (more than usual).

[image: offset hinge]

Why is that? The benefit might be not hitting the casing when the door can fully swing, but the screw in most hinges would be very close to the edge of the door/jamb because of that.

Comment: It looks like it's because you have a hinge made for a 1 ¾"  door (usually an exterior door) on a 1 ⅜" door in the bottom picture. 

Comment: Fancy molding can be thicker requiring a wider swing so the door will not hit when fully open.

Comment: For some installations its just for Style - no reason other than someone wanted an exposed look.